# What's with the dead end in the top right corner of Tropos?

Tags: owlboy

There's this dead end at the top left of Tropos. You can only get there with the help of...

> Spiderman. (Yes, he joins your party. Spoiler alert!)

[image: Game]

However, once you do get up here — something you are clearly supposed to be able to do given the ring — …nothing happens?

It's just this very conspicuously black screen. It doesn't look like a fake wall.

What gives?

Comment: SPOILER ALERT TOO FLIPIN LATE!

Comment: @ExperimentalRocket as if you totally didn't want spiderman on your party, cmon. He's like pew pew zip zoom!

Comment: lel ;) . Good luck to you and this mysterious "wall"

Comment: @badp, I'd like to know what you did. I never experienced this wall.

Comment: @Morgoth Nothing. I still don't know what's up. Maybe it's some DLC hook?

Answer (score 1):

This is the passage that leads you to the pirate base camp area, which you visit in the main questline after Spiderman joined the team in Mesos. You were given the hint that there's a passage from Tropos to the pirate's base camp behind a waterfall, which is this waterfall.

Once you completed the pirate base camp stage, this passage is inaccessible because the pirate base camp is no longer accessible.